# Access super class property from inherited class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift4

I have a class, MyContainer, which has another custom class as a variable. This other class, MyInterface, is a view controller super class, which gets extended by two other child custom classes, MyVCA and MyVCB. The reason for this is because I have a bottom button which is used across both screens - only the content has to get updated every time, which I do programmatically. There is also a content manager which I use to know which of the two child classes to use, called MyContentManager.

The problem I am having is when I am going from a previous view controller to either MyVCA or MyVCB, because depending on which one it is, a certain task needs to be done or not. I am instantiating the view for MyVCB from the storyboard like so:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Containers", 
    bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "my_container") as! MyContainer
vc.contentManager = MyContentManager(type: .type_my_vc_a)
vc.shouldDoTask = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

As can be seen I have created a flag, shouldDoTask, that needs to be set at this point (inside a previous view controller). But because it is set to the container super class, the children can not access it. So what needs to happen basically is that this flag needs to get propagated through the path MyContainer -> MyInterface -> MyVCA / MyVCB.

I have tried to use a property for the flag, in MyInterface:

```
private var _shouldDoTask: Bool = false
var shouldDoTask: Bool {
    set { _shouldDoTask = newValue }
    get { return _shouldDoTask }
}
```

And in MyContainer:

```
var content: MyInterface!

var shouldDoTask: Bool {
    set {
        if content != nil {
            content.shouldDoTask = newValue
        }
    }
    get {
        return (content != nil)
            ? content.shouldDoTask
            : false
    }
}
```

Then in MyVCA / MyVCB I can access it like this:

```
class MyVCA: MyInterface {

    func someMethod() {
        if self.shouldDoTask {
            // do task
        }
    }

}
```

This would work nicely, if it wasn't for the fact that the content is still nil when the flag gets set in the previous view controller. This is understandable because of course MyInterface has not been created yet. I am looking for a way past this. I have been thinking about a method that could get called in MyInterface's viewDidLoad method to set the flag, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: MyContainer is also a viewcontroller ?

Comment: @Gihan Yes it is.

Comment: On top of my mind what you could do is create a protocol with a callback method to set values in MyInterface. Implement the protocol in MyContainer and set it as a delegate object to myInterface. And then call the delegate method in myiterface viewdidload to set the values for you.

Comment: Did the answer help ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It crashes. I found another solution. Thank you though.

Comment: Oh alright. Still think this should be the right design pattern to follow.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I couldn't get it to work, but it is indeed a good design pattern. I only just saw that you edited your answer and it looks like that could solve the crash. I will +1 your answer.

Comment: Sure let me know If you need more help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Check if it helps.

```
protocol MyInterFaceDelegate {
     func setValues()
}

MyInterFace {
   let delegate : MyInterFaceDelegate

   viewDidLoad() {
      delegate.etValues()
    }
}

extension MyContainer : MyInterFaceDelegate {
   func setValues() {
      content.shouldDoTast = self.shouldDoTast
   }
 }
```

When you create MyInterFace() after that you set the delegate

```
content = MyInterFace()
content.delegate = self
```

Comment: This looks like it could work. Where do I initialise delegate? It crashes because it is nil when I run it